# Missing icons with CKEditor for Drupal 7

Tags: wysiwyg

I've recently installed CKEditor 4 for Drupal 7 module and some of the toolbar's icons don't seem to show up.

They are:
Add Media
Media
Teaser Break
and
YouTube (to name a few).

I've cleared the Drupal and Browser cache, but that hasn't helped. I've also ensured that I've got the right skins (reuploaded just in case). I tried multiple skins and these same buttons don't seem to want to appear.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to resolve this issue? Test thread is here. 
http://iloveqatar.net/forum/content/test-0#comment-36224

(Note, I installed CKEditor because I needed an easy solution for users to upload multiple images when created a post so I'm not really attached to CKEditor if someone has a better idea. I was using TinyMCE with the WYSIWYG module)

Answer (score 0):

Try re-upping the CKeditor library (not the module) and double-check that the owner/file permissions are set correctly on the server.

I believe TinyMCE also works with CKeditor. If you only need to attach images to content and don't need a WYSIWIG editor for your input area, you can add an Image or File field to the content type. If you're using a File field, you might also want to look up the File Entity and Media modules.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I've gone ahead and done that but sadly I've still got blank icons.

I do need a basic WYSIWIG, but the goal is to enable a solution where people can upload multiple files at once rather than one at a time (since we have people submitting pics)

Answer (score 0):

- You should check your browser console if there are any js errors appearing.
- also check in your wyswig profile page that you have checked the check-boxes for buttons to appear.
- Even if its not appearing it then you need to write some custom module code to add your buttons on toolbar.